# Sound not working with Alsamixer on ubuntu with Awesome WM

Tags: alsa, awesome

So on Ubuntu, when I boot into the normal window manager, everything works great. But when I boot into awesome, I need to use alsamixer to control the sound. The problem is that it no longer works after restarting for everything I try (headphones, default laptop speakers, and hdmi speakers).

I am able to use "amixer -c 1 sset 'Master' 75%" to change the volume from the terminal, and the changes can be seen from alsamixer, but still, no sound.

In the alsamixer menu, when pressing F6, it gives me 3 options: - (default), 0 HDA Intel HDMI, 1 HDA Intel PCH. Only the last option has anything meaningful with actual volume levels.

Comment: I had the same problem. Didn't find proper solution, but as workaround I switched to Gnome Shell and set up volume settings there, and then logged back to awesome and sound worked.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a solution but a workaround.

1. `sudo apt-get install pulseaudio pavucontrol`
2. Run `pulseaudio --start`. If pulseaudio was already running run `pulseaudio -k && pulseaudio --start`
3. Now you can access an easy config by running `pavucontrol`
4. You'll see the tab `Output Devices`. Click on it, and then there are 3 buttons in the right hand side. If you don't have the proper themes, they won't have any picture. Toggle the first button.

Now the headphones should work.

---

I'm using Awesome inside lubuntu 20.04, and here `pulseaudio` and `pavucontrol-qt` (lxqt version of pavucontrol) is installed. So just killed and started pulseaudio daemon and then toggle the headphones switch.